# Quantum Measurement in Different Basis

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-measurements

How can you make measurements on a qubit that is in a different basis than your measurement qubit? (i.e. You want to measure a single qubit in the $|+\rangle$/$|-\rangle$ basis but you can only make measurements in the computational basis).

Comment: In my opinion, a qubit is not in any *basis*, but it is in a state. You can describe this state in any basis. You may also want to specify, which kind of measurement you perform. Your question seems to be taken out of a specific context, which is not obvious for everyone. Please specify.

Comment: @flaudemus is correct. The basis is like the coordinate system. It is one way to represent a vector, but a vector is not tied to a basis.

Comment: The short answer is "you rotate the qubit first and then measure it". See the question linked in my previous comment for details.